# Memory ordering in sub-expressions of expressions carrying a dependency

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider the following code:

```
int data = 0;
std::atomic<int> ready = 0;

void writer_thread() {
    data = 25;
    ready.store(1, std::memory_order::release);
}

void reader_thread() {
    int ready_value = 0;
    while(!ready_value) { 
        ready_value = ready.load(std::memory_order::consume);
    }
    assert(data == 25); // #1
    assert(data + ready_value == 26); // #2
}
```

The assertion marked `#1` may or may not pass, because `data` does not carry a dependency from `ready`, which causes a race condition.

Assertion `#2` is more complicated. It would seem that the entire expression `data + ready_value == 26` carries a dependency from `ready`, as explained in [[intro.races#7]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#7) - an expression carries a dependency from its operands, and this relation is transitive.
But even if we establish that this is true, what does it imply about the memory ordering within this expression? Consider the following paragraph from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order):

> If an atomic store in thread A is tagged `memory_order_release` and an atomic load in thread B from the same variable that read the stored value is tagged `memory_order_consume`, all memory writes (non-atomic and relaxed atomic) that happened-before the atomic store from the point of view of thread A, become visible side-effects **within those operations in thread B into which the load operation carries dependency**, that is, once the atomic load is completed, **those operators and functions in thread B that use the value obtained from the load are guaranteed to see what thread A wrote to memory**.

I am not sure how to interpret the emphasized sentences. Does the guarantee about the visibility of the side-effects apply to every sub-expression as well?

Let's take the addition expression `data + ready_value`, which, as a whole, carries a dependency from `ready`. While evaluating the `data` sub-expression of this expression, are the side-effects visible or not?
If they are, then I believe the assertion `#2` does not contain a race condition.
But if they are not, then the evaluation of the sub-expression `data` might produce a `0`, and the assertion contains a race condition.

Comment: It seems straightforward to me: `assert(data + ready_value == 26);` includes evaluating the expression `data` which appears as a sub-expression.  This evaluation doesn't happen-before the `data = 25` in the other thread, nor vice versa, hence this is a data race and is UB.  The intention of memory ordering is to allow or inhibit various speculative and out-of-order capabilities of the hardware, and it's not reasonable to expect the hardware to know whether the load of `data` is part of a larger expression in the source code, so the answer can't really depend on that context.

Comment: By the way, for an example like `assert(data);` saying that "the assertion may or may not pass" understates the problem.  It's a data race, so you don't just get an indeterminate value, you get undefined behavior.  The assertion may pass, or not pass, or pass but crash later, or cause demons to fly out your nose.

Answer (score 1):

> Assertion #2 is more complicated.

No, [it isn't](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.races#21):

> The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other, except for the special case for signal handlers described below. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

Accessing `data` is an "action". Both `reader_thread` and `writer_thread` attempt to access `data`. Pursuant to [[intro.races]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.races#2):

> Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location ([intro.memory]) and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location.

`writer_thread` assigns to `data`. `reader_thread` reads from `data`. The two actions therefore potentially conflict.

Both accesses are "potentially concurrent", as they are accessed from different threads.

Neither access is atomic. Neither access is one of the signal handling exceptions.

That leaves "happens before". Well, `consume` only matters for the atomic object being accessed and the expressions and side-effects that generated that value. Consume [only gives us the "dependency-ordered before"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.races#8) relation. And this only applies to the written atomic object and any side-effects used to write that atomic value, through the "carries dependency" relationship as you cited.

`ready_value` might carry the dependency of `ready`, but `data` is not part of that dependency chain.

As such, `writer_thread`'s write to `data` does not "happen before" `reader_thread`'s read of `data`. Therefore, accessing its data is undefined behavior.

Nowhere is there a statement about accessing `ready` or `ready_value`.

*Always*. That's just how consume works.